# Recommendation needed: O/R mapper

Tags: .net, sql-server, orm

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What ORM frameworks for .NET Do You Like Best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249550/what-orm-frameworks-for-net-do-you-like-best)
>   [Best way to access a SQL Server database using C# .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989638/best-way-to-access-a-sql-server-database-using-c-net)

Hello,

Can someone recommend a good O/R mapper for SQL Server 2008/.NET ?

I am looking for it to also support stored procs not just tables.

Thank you!

Comment: I like Linq2SQL, but some will complain that it is deprecated.

Comment: @leppie : Any such complaint would be false. It was just updated for .NET 4.0, in fact.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Reference for that statement? I believe they said they werent doing more work on it. And if they did, why are the trivial bugs still present?

Comment: @leppie Search for 'linq to sql .net 4.0' and you'll find about half a million results, many which detail the changes in the new version.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Thanks, still dunno why they didn't bother fixing a trivial bug...

Comment: There're lots of threads on SO about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net+orm. I suggest you to read them and then refine your question to be more specific.

Comment: @Leppie: Which trivial bug are you talking about? They did fix some bugs in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/427574/linq2sql-using-ilistsource-getlist-on-a-dataquery-that-was-constructed-with-oftype-fails

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 3):

[NHibernate](http://www.nhforge.org)

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)

You'll hear arguments about the pros and cons of each. Personally I'd suggest NHibernate at the moment. It is the more mature of the two and has a very active community working on it. It does have a steep learning curve though.

I'd add that the main feature in favour of EF over NH is that EF has full LINQ support. NH2 has partial support as a separate compondent available at present. However, NH3 Alpha has now been released and it has a much better LINQ provider.

However, it very much depends on your requirements.

Comment: Personally, I would never go near NHibernate again :)

Comment: @leppie why? it is one of the most mature ORM

Comment: Despite my recommendation of L2S/EF in my answer, I think NHibernate is certainly an excellent choice as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

**NHibernate is the way to go.**

See http://nhforge.org and http://sf.net/projects/nhibernate for more information.

The main difference between Entity Framework and NHibernate is that Entity Framework is only for Microsoft SQL Server (Oracle is kind of supported, but support is not ideal). NHibernate supports many many many databases.

There are however much more differences between them. A query on [comparison nhibernate "entity framework"](http://www.google.com/search?q=comparison+nhibernate+%22entity+framework%22) gives many sources of information.

Comment: There is still much more between the two ORMs than the range of supported databases. The poster has already said that this is for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @David Neala - Yes, you're right.

Comment: There are a range of database providers for Entity Framework. Look at this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Linq to SQL may be a good option for you. Entity Framework is another. Both would meet your requirements.

Technically speaking, the O/R tools you would use for Linq to SQL with SQL Server and .NET would be the O/R Designer in Visual Studio or SQLMetal. Both enable you to model the data as well as stored procedures/functions.

If you have Visual Studio, you would simply add a new object and choose either ADO.NET Entity classes or Linq to SQL classes, depending on which you were using.

Without Visual Studio, you can use the SQLMetal command-line tool to generate L2S classes, also:

SQLMetal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx

Answer (score -2):

built-in [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx)

Comment: LINQ is not an ORM - it is a method by which data sources (database, XML, objects in memory etc.) can be queried.