# make application responsive and fast

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xbap

I created a wpf browser application ,and I hosted it in a live server ,it is a Inventory Management application ,which uses database heavily for saving, updating and selecting data.On save and select operation it takes very long time to save and fetch data to and from database.In the meantime (when save or select data from database) the application is irresponsive .How to make the application fast when dealing with database and how to make the application responsive during that operation .I am totally messed up ,its very kind if anyone has the answer .
Is using stored procedures instead of raw sql bring performance or not?

Edit

My application interact with database by using raw sql statements.

Comment: Is it a native application or hybrid one?

Comment: Look into the `async/await` pattern for achieving asynchrony as a starting point.

Comment: How are you interacting with the database?

Comment: Just use threads and backgroundworkers and your should be ok.
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: @Anuraj , its a native application

Comment: @e.campver ,Iam interact with the database by using raw sql queries

Comment: I just narrow the question,Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Responsive Application

In order to make your application responsive you need to make every interaction with the database in a new thread or task. You could also use the new C# 5.0 features `await` and `async`.

Your current application is blocking because the main thread is handling database operations as well as user interface, so what you need to do is to handle these two separate functionalities in separate threads.

### Fast Database Access

I don't know how are you dealing with the database right now, but you could definitely use some kind of ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate. 
For better performance, **but much less readable and mantainable code**, which is really important, you could use raw sql.

Comment: yes I am using raw sql statements to interact my database

Comment: @Mussammil: Then the only way of getting a better performance is to optimize your sql statements and/or redesign your database diminishing its level of normalization to avoid expensive join operations.

Comment: ok Suppose if i Put entire database operation in a new thread ,while save if I click the clear button(or any button )on the UI will cause the pblms right ,because the UI is responsive ,so what we do?

Comment: @Mussammil: what is the expected behavior when you click any button while saving? or when you click the clear button specifically? what problems do you refer to? help me to help you ;)

Comment: ,ok suppose when save button click the data on the page is inserted/updated to many tables approximately 30 tables this will take some time right .In the meantime if I click clear button which clears all the fields on the page and make ready for new insert.But acutually the save operation is not completed yet this will lead a inconsistancy

Comment: @Mussammil: But the clear button is not supposed to cancel the insert/update is it? If the answer is no, I don't see the inconsistency: you are saving some data and you are also about to add some more while the work is done. If the answer is yes, then it's more complicated and I believe you could post it as another question.

Answer (score -1):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989638/best-way-to-access-a-sql-server-database-using-c-sharp-net)

to access DB faster in .NEt i am sure it not problem with c# but for querying and retireving DB u need to have better mechanism

Comment: ,what kind of mechanism